# highcharts line not fully plotted

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart combined with a line drawing across the chart.
When decreasing the width of the chart container to a value smaller than 357px the horizontal line is only drawn half way instead of the full width.

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chartcontainer',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                borderRadius:0,
                marginRight: 22,
                marginBottom: 140
            },
            title: {
                text: 'test norm',
                align: 'left'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'x',
                    style: {

                    }
                },
                categories: ['2008','2009','2010','2011','2012'],
                labels: {
                    style: {
                    }
                }
            },
            { //secondary xAxis for range and norm values
              gridLineWidth: 0, 
              labels:{
                  enabled:false
              },
              lineWidth:0,
              tickWidth:0,
              opposite: true,
              minPadding:0,
              maxPadding:0
            }
            ],
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'y',
                    style: {
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    style: {
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                width:700,
                borderRadius: 0,
                shadow:false,
                floating:true,          
                borderWidth: 0                                  
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                borderRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    font: 'bold 11px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },                          
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {
                         enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false
                }
            },
            series: [{ name: 'A', shadow: false, data: [8,2,8,4,6] },{ name: 'B', shadow: false, data: [1,4,2,3,4] },{ name: 'C', shadow: false, data: [4,16,8,12,16] },{ name: 'E', shadow: false, data: [8,4,6,8,2] },{
type:'line',
name:'Norm',

data:[
    { 
        y:10.000000,            
        x:0.000000,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            align: 'left',
            formatter:function(){return 'Norm: ' + this.y;},
            style: {fontWeight:'bold'}
        },

    },
    {
        y:10.000000,
        x:1.000000,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            formatter:function(){return 'Norm: ' + this.y;},
            style: {fontWeight:'bold'}
        },
    }
],
color: '#01A1EB',
lineWidth:1,
dashStyle:'Solid',
shadow: {
    opacity:0.1
},
enableMouseTracking:false,
marker:{enabled:false},
xAxis:1,
showInLegend: true
```

}]
            });

See my jsfiddle example here:
The line fully drawn:

http://jsfiddle.net/ramon_ackermann/WwSbT/7/

The line only half way:
http://jsfiddle.net/ramon_ackermann/WwSbT/8/

Any ideas what might cause this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotline would be my preferred option as well.

If you need it to be a series for some reason, however, you can do it like this:

1) set your min x value for the line at -0.5, max x value at 4.5
2) set xAxis min at 0 and max at 4
3) forget about the secondary x axis

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/WwSbT/10/

```
for the x axis:
xAxis: [{
  min:0,
  max:4,
}]

and then in the data:
...
  y:10.000000,            
  x:-0.5,
...
  y:10.000000,
  x:4.5,
```

The second x axis appears to be part of the problem.  If you hide the norm series, and then reshow it, it fills the plot area properly.

Comment: I have to use the series, as in some charts multiple steps can occur per line. But your proposal with the min and max and removing the extra worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Use Plotline on the y axis instead: http://jsfiddle.net/paranoir/WwSbT/9/

```
plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 1,
    value: 10
}]
```