# highcharts 3, line on column chart

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/ramon_ackermann/PhjX7/2/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type:'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        min:0,
        max:0,
        categories: ["test"]
    },
    series: [{
        "name": "ABELO",
        "data": [
            0.73
        ]
    },{
        "name": "UAAU",
        "data": [
            0.77
        ]
    },{
        "name": "ANCB",
        "data": [
            1.72
        ]
    },
             {
        "name": "avg",
        "type": "line",
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "data": [
            {
                "x": -0.5,
                "y": 1.5
            },{
                "y": 1.5,
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "align": "right",
                    "verticalAlign": "bottom",
                    "formatter": function(){
                        return 'avg:  ' + this.y;
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "fontWeight": "normal"
                    },
                    "x": 0.5
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

});
```

});

Before updgrading to Highcharts 3, the code above would work properly, drawing the line from left to right, but since I'm trying to upgrade to v3, I can't get the line to draw all the way to the right.

I devised the above solution from my previous question / answers ([highcharts line not fully plotted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107302/highcharts-line-not-fully-plotted))

The above sample is a simplified version of what I need, unfortunately plotLines is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to extend another point onto your `avg` line:

```
...,{"x": 1.5, "y": 1.5}]
```

Why is a `plotLine` not appropriate?

Comment: Before, a chart like above, would extend from -0.5 to +0.5 while 0 was in the center. so now it's from -0.5 to 1.5 with 1 in the center? I can't use plotLine because they extend accross a whole chart, but the line values can vary accross a complete chart

Comment: It looks like there was a change in the start position of the xAxis. Instead of index 0 being on the xAxis 0 it is on the xAxis 1.

Comment: Problem with your solution, while it plots a complete line, I can't get the dataLabel all the way to the right (or left for that matter)

Comment: That is because you have your dataLabel on what is now the 2nd data point. The dataLabel stays near this point. So, in order to show it on the left or right of the line move the dataLabel to one of those points. Since the y-value at each of these 3 points is identical then the dataLabel should be as well.

Comment: That would be the plan, but unfortunately, it won't budge: http://jsfiddle.net/ramon_ackermann/PhjX7/4/

Comment: Interesting. I removed your double quotes around part of the properties and there was a change in the layout. Where do you want the dataLabel to be at?

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use plotLine or use renderer.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. Unfortunately, neither option shows up in the legend either, plus, the renderer is impossible to place correctly in a dynamic chart. I guess I will have to take this up with our client and see what he wants to do. It's a shame that they changed how this works in the update.